# flex button event handler

Tags: apache-flex, flex4, mouseevent

I have some buttons in a BorderContainer and I would like to execute the attached event when the user click on the buttons. But, the parent has a click event too.

I would like to execute the action A when the user click on the button A, the action B with the button B and the action C if the user click on the background.

Actually, if I add the eventHandler to the bordercontainer, the buttons don't work anymore. No mouse cursor, no mousehover effect, and if you click on it, it's the action C which is launched.

My bordercontainer:

```
useHandCursor = true;
mouseChildren = false;
buttonMode = true;
```

In both buttons and bordercontainer I use the `MouseEvent.Click` event and both call the same function "click" which will execute different actions depending the properties of the `event.target`.

Comment: mouseChildren = false; that means, that children of border container will not react on mouse interactions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My bad. Thank to Timofei.

Both the bordercontainer and the click function were wrong.

In the bordercontainer, `mouseChildren` had to be set at `true`, which will let the children get the event too.

And in my click function, using `event.target` was a bad idea. It tried to get the properties from the bordercontainreskin. I had to use `event.currentTarget` instead. Finally I added a `event.stopPropagation()` to prevent the bordercontainer to catch the event too when the user click on a button. And now, everything is working well now.

Thank you